# page contents keep shifting on inital load. Could it be that everything isn't rendered correctly?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, react-bootstrap

I have a published gatsby site on netlify, and whenever the page loads initially, the inner contents shift. I don't understand why it keeps shifting on load. could it be something to do with how everything is being rendered? here is a link to the live site:
https://compassionate-kilby-40d38d.netlify.com/dev-design/

Comment: have you tried running `gatsy clean` before publishing your gatsyjs site on netlify? https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/debugging-cache-issues/

Comment: When I load the page the first time the content shift upwards a bit. I know from my gatsby site that some parts shift around a little too. I don't see it as an issue because it happens immediatly and you have to pay attention to actually see it. It never gets in the way of the user experience. I always thought it has something to do with the parts of the CSS loading and getting applied at different stages of the loading process in the browser but this is just an assumption.

Comment: Are you using styled components?

Answer (score 1):

Looks fine to me (Firefox Developer 69.0b9) - quick FOUT on page load, but the content itself is fixed.